# HTML tables and CSS in email

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I understand putting HTML and CSS in emails is a pain and some things don't work. So therefore I have to create my layout in table elements which is fine.

Now take this example:

```
print"<center><Table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=1 style=\"width:680px;border:1px solid blue\">";
print"<tr><td>";

print "<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=1 style=\"width:220px;border:1px solid blue;\">";
        print "<tr><td>";
            print "testing testing";
        print "</tr></td>";
        print "<tr><td>";
            print "testing it";
        print "<tr></td>";
                print "<tr><td>";
            print "testing it";
        print "<tr></td>";



print "</table><br>";

print "<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=1 style=\"width:220px;border:1px solid blue;\">";
        print "<tr><td>";
            print "testing testing";
        print "</tr></td>";
        print "<tr><td>";
            print "testing it";
        print "<tr></td>";
                print "<tr><td>";
            print "testing it";
        print "<tr></td>";



print "</table>";

print"</tr></td>";
print "</table></center>";
```

This outputs like so in the browser (which is fine):

[image: tables]

Now the problem is I want the inner tables to float to the left so they appear next to each other, instead of beneath each other. Obviously floats don't work in Outlook, so how else could I do something like that?

Comment: can u screen the result that you want ? width legend (width, height of each elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest them inside another table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            TABLE 1 GOES HERE
        </td>
        <td>
            TABLE 2 GOES HERE
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: doesnt work for me because i have this just under the outer table declaration: print "<tr><td style=\"max-width:678px;min-width:678px;\">";
 print "<img src=\"http://www.parkesmachinetools.co.uk/images/emailbanner.png\">";
 print "</tr></td>";

Comment: @user3332590 You need to make sure you have the same number of cells within each row in the table, or the layout will not work. You could also set `colspan="2"` onto your `<td>` so that it spans across the extra missing cell column

Comment: Well you see, what if there is 4 columns nested inside, or even 20, the data is loaded dynamic you see.

Comment: @user3332590 The colspan is only required per table scope, so if the data is added to your inner table, then there is no problem, you just need to make sure the inner table has the same number of cells in each row. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/andyp/AQz7T/.

Answer (score 1):

**All CSS Properties not supported in email clients(outlook), so create your table structure properly.**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uZ7G8/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<table style="border:1px solid #00F;" width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #00F;" align="left" valign="top">Table One</td>
    <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #00F; border-left:1px solid #00F;" align="left" valign="top">Option 1</td>
    <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #00F; border-left:1px solid #00F;" align="left" valign="top">Option 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top">Table Two</td>
    <td style="border-left:1px solid #00F;" align="left" valign="top">Option 1</td>
    <td style="border-left:1px solid #00F;" align="left" valign="top">Option 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table style="border:1px solid #00F;" width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><table width="250" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #00F;" align="left" valign="top">Table Two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #00F;" align="left" valign="top">Option 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left" valign="top">Option 2</td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
    <td style="border-left:1px solid #00F;" align="left" valign="top"><table width="250" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #00F;" align="left" valign="top">Table One</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #00F;" align="left" valign="top">Option 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left" valign="top">Option 2</td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Andy's answer will place the table cells next to each other - that is the most consistent technique. However, you were asking for a `float` equivalent. For html email that is `align="left"`.

Example:

```
<table width="90%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#bbbbbb">
  <tr>
    <td align="left">

      <table width="150" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#333333">
        <tr>
          <td height="100">
            ...
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table width="150" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#555555">
        <tr>
          <td height="100">
            ...
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table width="150" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#777777">
        <tr>
          <td height="100">
            ...
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When viewed in an email client, the tables will bump down when there isn't enough room (mobile for example). This is the behavior that `float` has, while Andy's solution is fixed, meaning your tables (td's) will always be next to each other.